# Converting from VB to C#, storing values from subroutines

Tags: c#, vb6, vb6-migration

I am re-writing an old VB application in C#, this application is some sort of calculator. So it consists of a bunch of subroutines which takes some values, and calculate some new values(intermediate results), which is later used in some other calculations.

The way they do this is like this:

```
int in = 4;
Call routine(in, outFromRoutine1);

Call routine2(outFromRoutine1, outFromRoutine2);
```

The default in VB6 is pass by reference, so I could do the same in C# like this:

```
int in = 4;
int outFromRoutine2 = 0;
Routine(in, ref outFromRoutine1);

int outFromRoutine2 = 0;
Routine2(outFromRoutine1, ref outFromRoutine2);
```

But I am just thinking if this is considered a weird way to do this in C#? That this is just some sort of weird VB way of doing it.
Is there any problem with doing it like this in C# also?

Comment: functions are more normal.  ```var result = routine2(routine1(in))```   but not knowing the code in the call, this might not be correct

Comment: ByRef was common in VB6 code only because it was the default.  So first thing you want to make sure is that it is actually *necessary* to pass by ref, it very often isn't.  Also consider the new C# v7 goody available in VS2017, you can write Routine(in, out int outFromRoutine1) so you don't have to declare the variable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

C# offers both the ref (parameter is input and output) and out (parameter is output only) that allow you to use parameters to the method as outputs from the method as well.  That said, in general, it is considered to be best practice use return statements to return values in C#.  If you are moving forward with visual studio 2017, you can also use the new function of C# that allows you to return multiple values from a single method.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/csharp/language-reference/keywords/method-parameters

Comment: Not sure why this has been down voted. This to me points to the right way of doing things (moving the app to pass values back rather than modify a variable by ref. Out is also a good point which I think should be considered by someone clearly newish to C#.I think out is good practise if you are going to stick with the "VB Way".

Comment: Thanks! I didn't know about the new C# feature, nor about the use of out.

Answer (score 0):

While the above pattern can be implemented in VB6, VB.net or C#, it is not idiomatic in any of them.  All 3 languages recognize the distinction between methods that return a value and those that don't, and people are encouraged to use the appropriate one.

While VB6 did default to byref, you'll still find that most code used functions to return values instead of subs.

In .net (both VB and C#), ref and out vars are generally used appropriately to initialize a resource or to return multiple values.  Returning multiple values may soon become less common due to support for named tuples.